# Index a continuous stream of documents in SOLR

Tags: perl, indexing, solr

I need to index thousands of documents continuously into SOLR.
The documents are picked up from a redis like queue ( SSDB) and then indexed into SOLR

Whenever I use the library function $solr->add()  there is a new HTTP call made to solr. Is there a better mechanism to index bulk items into SOLR ?

Comment: Which Perl module are you using to talk to the Solr?

Comment: If you receive several documents at the same time, you can add them all in a single HTTP request - or you can delay the add until you've received x number of documents. The commit is usually the expensive part of the update, so extending the commitWithin time or the time before you issue the commit could also help. How do you do the adds now? How often do new documents arrive? How fast do you want the documents to be visible? Have you looked at the NRT features of Solr?

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of points you should consider:

First, I would suggest to de-couple the process of pulling data from the queue and indexing into Solr. What I mean by this is have a process that would pull the data from the queue, massage it correctly and write out solr json file. The file should have multiple records; the number will be determined by the size of each record and the total number of items you will have in each batch. Play around with different settings.

Then have another process index those files, you can have multiple processes indexing these into Solr as well. This will ensure that your DE-queuing process is not hung up on indexing items to Solr; which is not always quick.

Next; evaluate your library of choice. If you have the data local to a Solr server, you can pass the path via a GET request to index it or you can stream it over the network. The first approach will be faster, however it requires you to store JSON locally on the Solr box.

Finally, review your committing strategy. What kind of delay is acceptable? Are you doing a lot of faceting or FQ queries? If some delay is alight and the answer to your second question is yes, I would suggest to have a very aggressive hard commit and relaxed soft commit. If you need new items to be picked up very quickly, then consider lowering the soft commit while testing performance until you find a good balance.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Having multiple processes seems more complicated , I already have a process that generates these documents into a Redis queue ( SSDB actually) The SOLR is always going to be in the same LAN. My items in SOLR are not going to be picked up immediately , so committing can always be delayed